# Editing the contents of an object tag with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, append

I have this JQuery function:

```
var objects = document.querySelectorAll('object');

// Iterate through objects
$('object').each( function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('data');
    $(this).append('<a href="'+link'">click here</a>');

});
```

It goes through all `<object>` items in a page and appends a link to the end of them (all of the objects in this case are used to create an embed document.) However, I want to edit the function so that it also edits an attribute in the object tag, preferably changing the name attribute, and also add an if statement to check to see if the object tag contains this new name.

Comment: Use the `.attr()` method... like `$(this).attr('name', 'new-name')`

Comment: To check whether there is an object with the given name... `if($('object').is('[name="name-to-check"]')){alert('name-exists')}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr) to get/set the name attribute, also you can use [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is) along with [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
// Iterate through objects
var $objects = $('object');
$objects.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.append('<a href="' + $this.attr('data')
    '">click here</a>');

  var nametoset = ''; //some logic to find the name
  if ($objects.is('[name="' + nametoset + '"]')) {
    //name already exists so do something 
  } else {
    $this.attr('name', nametoset);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('object').each( function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('data');
    var newlink = $('<a href="'+link'">click here</a>');
    newLink.attr("name","jonny");
    $(this).append(newLink);
});
```

OR

```
$('object').each( function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('data');
    var newname = "jonny";
    var newlink =$ ('<a href="'+link+'" name="'+newname+'">click here</a>');
    $(this).append(newLink);
});
```